# Are there any items that are unique or shouldn't be sold?

Tags: i-am-setsuna

Enemies don't drop gold, but they drop a ton of items. Some of these can be sold to obtain Spritnite, but others can be sold to different merchants.

Is it safe to just empty my inventory whenever I reach a town?